# Any quick way to set a DNS record on all domains in Cloudflare?

Tags: cloudflare

If I am managing, say, 20 domains in Cloudflare and I want to set or modify a DNS record in all of them at once, is there any short cut to doing so in the user interface without manually doing it 20 times or writing software to do it via the API?

For example, to change the SPF/TXT record on all my domains at once.

Answer (score 4):

The short way to do this is using the API. A short script in your preferred language will do the trick.

https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-update-dns-record